# I have upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and now my internet connection is GONE

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, internet

I finally upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and the system does not connect to the internet anymore. LAN and WLN gets connected, but no internet. I tried all kinds of settings, what was recommended here doesn't apply,  and have already wasted 4 days. What can I do?

Terminal response from pinging Google DNS (8.8.8.8):

```
ich@ThinkPad-Edge:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=28.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=115 time=27.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=115 time=22.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=115 time=23.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=115 time=22.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=115 time=24.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=115 time=26.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=115 time=22.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=9 ttl=115 time=22.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=10 ttl=115 time=25.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=11 ttl=115 time=24.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=12 ttl=115 time=25.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=13 ttl=115 time=25.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=14 ttl=115 time=23.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=15 ttl=115 time=27.5 ms
```

..and so on, it continues indefinitely..

```
ich@ThinkPad-Edge:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:eb:69:d1:4d:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:a9:82:2c:05:36 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 2381sec preferred_lft 2381sec
    inet6 fe80::2b16:833c:a473:e0ec/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
ich@ThinkPad-Edge:~$
```

NEW:

```
ich@ThinkPad-Edge:~$ nslookup google.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find google.com: SERVFAIL
```

Comment: You've not said if server, or desktop.  Have you dropped to terminal (it can be done using GUI too but we don't know what you're using) and ensured the network interface is recognized (you maybe using the same kernel as you were in 16.04, or it may have changed; you've given few details so we cannot know). Can you `ping` your router? ping externally when using IP addresses (eg. `ping 8.8.8.8` to ping google) .. ie. if that works; it's a DNS issue; or the human name 'google.com' getting translated to IP addresses (numbers) is your issue.  More details provided allow us to better help you.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1356804/edit) to include a clear, readable photo showing the complete output of `ip addr`.

Comment: This is a regular (Lenovo Edge) laptop computer. I have used it with Ubuntu 14 and 16 since several years and everything worked. Now after this update the internet is messed up, although the network manager says "connected".

Comment: Here the readouts:

Comment: If you get a ping from Google (8.8.8.8), you have internet. Maybe your DNS configuration is the problem, as guiverc suggests. Please insert the output of this command: `nslookup google.com`

Comment: So know we know that 1) You have internet connection (since you can `ping 8.8.8.8`), and 2) You can't resolve DNS names (since `nslookup google.com` is failing). This is troubleshooting 101, since the problem is now isolated to your DNS setup.

Answer (score 1):

I had DNS problems in 18.04 as well. This is what I did to fix them.

```
 sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
 sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Unfortunately I do not remember the source, but likely it was a Q&A on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf  file.
There was a line which had to be commented out with an # (dns=dnsmasq).
After a restart, the machine could connect to the internet.
Thanks a lot for all your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Along side with `nameserver 127.0.0.53` you should have `search gatewayIP`. In order to have this permanent edit /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head and add the missing one.

Comment: The command "search" was not found, it says?